# Answer posts via mail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I tried to find something to help me in already asked questions but I don't seem to be lucky.

What I'd like to achieve is similar to facebook's answer through mail.

If my user gets a private message I send him an email to notify him. I'd like to let him answer to the mail and post the answer as a reply to the pm.

How can I achieve that?

I thought about creating an email with some sort of token as name in order to know what pm to reply and make it in a "secure" way using the token. Let's pretend I write with 1451441ttrwwrw45@mysite.com.

So i'd know the token is Mr X and the pm to answer is N.

I stop on the practical side. How do I create a temp email on the fly to notify with the desired "account name" (token)?
Is it necessary that the mail server used to send and read is on the same server?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How to do this depends on what email server you're using.  Many email servers allow you to define rules for which incoming messages are delivered to which mailboxes.  Sometimes they'll allow a special address such as address+uniquestring@mysite.com to be delivered to the mailbox for address@mysite.com, for example.

Comment: @BillShannon Thanks Bill. That would be something like a catchall mail right? What about "on the fly" mails? Would I be fine with some sort of temp aliases?

Comment: Again, it depends on your server.

Comment: @BillShannon For testing purposes i'm using a hosting  mail server on servage.net

Comment: Ok, so what mail server are you hosting?  What does their documentation say?

Comment: I'm getting closer to the "solution". I managed testing the sending of email with an arbitrary replyto (token@mailserver.com). I then have a catchall on the mailserver and attaching a messagecountlistener to the imap I get all emails sent to the mailserver. There I can look at the fake mail to get the token and so on...